# How to access docker cli like PostgreSQL

Tags: docker

I have installed Docker CE in remote machine. I want to use docker cli from local machine like PostgreSQL.

I always type like this to login and exec PostgreSQL.

```
$ psql -U username -p 5432 -h myserver -d db -c 'SELECT * FROM tbl'
```

Do anyone has any idea?

Comment: Have you expose the port?

Comment: I want to just handle docker daemon not docker container.

Comment: oh, sorry, you can maybe check this https://www.kevinkuszyk.com/2016/11/28/connect-your-docker-client-to-a-remote-docker-host/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you have the Docker client running on one machine, and you want to use it to manage a Docker host running remotely.

To do that you can set the DOCKER_HOST environment variable to the remote machine. Please use TLS if you're accessing a machine remotely, otherwise anyone can access your Docker daemon remotely.

As an example:

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://<remote docker host IP>:2376
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=<path to cert>
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

If you don't want to set the ENV variables you can just specify the host on the CLI every time - this example displays the docker version on a remote host located at `<remote docker host IP>` and authenticating using the TLS certs in the current directory.

```
docker --tlsverify \
--tlscacert=ca.pem \
--tlscert=cert.pem \
--tlskey=key.pem \
-H=<remote docker host IP>:2376 \
version
```

For more information on securing the Docker daemon check out [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/)